# Calculate pi with MATLAB, bad results

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, arbitrary-precision

I'm using this .m file to calculate pi with MATLAB

```
function calpi(n)
    S = 0;
    for i=1:n
        if mod(i,2) == 0
            S=S-1/(2*i-1)*(4*((1/5)^(2*i-1))-(1/239)^(2*i-1));
        else
            S=S+1/(2*i-1)*(4*((1/5)^(2*i-1))-(1/239)^(2*i-1));
        end    
    end
    S = 4*S;
    S=vpa(S,50)
```

When `n <= 8`, it's alright.
But when `n >= 9`, the result turns exactly into the actual pi.
All I want is to get the actual result to analyse this method.

```
>> calpi(9)
S =
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751

>> vpa(pi,50)
ans =
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751
```

What's wrong with MATLAB?

Comment: Odd. How can this even work? You are adding the precision *after* the calculation.

Comment: Please explain what output you are expecting.

Comment: The symbolic toolbox is odd. The output of `vpa(sym(x,'d'),50)` is what I would expect as default when calling `vpa(x,50)`. Instead there is some rounding-magic going on.

Comment: What is the formula you are using to calculate pi? I wasn't able to find it on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi

Comment: Are you perhaps incorrectly using `vpa` to display more digits of a double precision value? Use `format long` to display/print the full precision (or close to it) of floating point values.

Comment: There is a matlab code on my book.It use vpa at the end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: You need to specify to MATLAB that you want variable precision **before** you actually do the calculation.

What your function `calpi` does is: Compute an approximation using the built-in `double`-precision datatype and then convert it to a symbolic `vpa` *afterwards*. You can't get an approximation that is more accurate than a `double` if you do it this way.

So a first step would be to use `vpa` *before* the calculation:

```
function S = calpi(n)
S = vpa(0,50);
for i = 1:n
    if mod(i,2) == 0
        S=S-1/(2*i-1)*(4*((1/5)^(2*i-1))-(1/239)^(2*i-1));
    else
        S=S+1/(2*i-1)*(4*((1/5)^(2*i-1))-(1/239)^(2*i-1));
    end
end
S = 4*S;
```

If you have a look at the output, you will see that still only double-precision results are returned.
This is because when the calculation `1/(2*i-1)*...` is done, it is still evaluated using only double-precision. You can fix this by using the symbolic evaluation

```
vpa(subs('1/(2*i-1)*(4*((1/5)^(2*i-1))-(1/239)^(2*i-1))','i',i),50)
```

instead:

```
function S = calpi(n)
S = vpa(0,50);
for i = 1:n
    tmp = vpa(subs('1/(2*i-1)*(4*((1/5)^(2*i-1))-(1/239)^(2*i-1))','i',i),50);
    if mod(i,2) == 0
        S = S-tmp;
    else
        S = S+tmp;
    end
end
S = 4*S;
```

---

As for why your calculation is actually *more exact* than you would expect:
When you call `vpa(x,50)` with a normal `double` variable `x`, the default conversion `sym(x,'r')` happens. (See `help sym`).

> `'r'` stands for 'rational'.  Floating point numbers obtained by
>       evaluating expressions of the form `p/q`, `p*pi/q`, `sqrt(p)`, `2^q` and `10^q`
>       for modest sized integers `p` and `q` are converted to the corresponding
>       symbolic form.

So when you call `vpa(S,50)`, MATLAB checks if your double value is near some fraction `p/q` or a fraction `p*pi/q`, etc., and if it is, it rounds the value towards that. In our case if `S` is a sufficiently good approximation of `pi`, `vpa(S,50)` is rounded towards `sym('pi')`. If we didn't want to round, we could use something like `vpa(sym(S,'f'), 50)` instead.

Comment: @KevinLing: So do you want to use `double` precision to compute the approximation of `pi` or `vpa` precision?

Comment: I m new to Matlab. I was intended to calculate pi with that formula and to reveal the difference between this and the real pi.